# What can i do to fix my SQLIte connection string

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am working with SQLite for the first time and now when I want to add something to the DB, It throws an error saying:

" Invalid ConnectionString format, cannot parse: string value to split cannot be null"

Here is my code so far for this(I am working from a tutorial):

```
String dbConnection;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Default Constructor for SQLiteDatabase Class.
    /// </summary>
    public void SQLiteDatabase()
    {
        dbConnection = "Data Source = StockDB.s3db; Version = 3;";

    }

 public int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)
    {
        SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
        cnn.Open(); //error thrown here
        SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
        mycommand.CommandText = sql;
        int rowsUpdated = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn.Close();
        return rowsUpdated;
    }
```

I dont know if you need the code for the sql query aswell but:

```
DBHelper db = new DBHelper();
UserInfo UI = new UserInfo();
UI.UserName = "henry";
UI.Code = 123;
UI.Role = "LEADER";    
string sql = "INSERT INTO User (Username, Code, Role)" +
                    "VALUES (" + UI.UserName + "" + UI.Code.ToString() + "" + UI.Role + ")";
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
```

I don't know how to fix this. I can read from the database no problem.

Extra Information:

```
namespace Stock_A_Lot
{
public class DBHelper
{

    String dbConnection;
    /// <summary>
    ///     Default Constructor for SQLiteDatabase Class.
    /// </summary>
    public void SQLiteDatabase()
    {
        dbConnection = "Data Source = StockDB.s3db; Version = 3;";
    }       
    public DataTable GetDataTable(string sql)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
            cnn.Open();
            SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
            mycommand.CommandText = sql;
            SQLiteDataReader reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(reader);
            reader.Close();
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
        return dt;
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///     Allows the programmer to interact with the database for purposes other than a query.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sql">The SQL to be run.</param>
    /// <returns>An Integer containing the number of rows updated.</returns>
    public int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)
    {
        SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
        cnn.Open();
        SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
        mycommand.CommandText = sql;
        int rowsUpdated = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn.Close();
        return rowsUpdated;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Allows the programmer to retrieve single items from the DB.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sql">The query to run.</param>
    /// <returns>A string.</returns>
    public string ExecuteScalar(string sql)
    {
        SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
        cnn.Open();
        SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
        mycommand.CommandText = sql;
        object value = mycommand.ExecuteScalar();
        cnn.Close();
        if (value != null)
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
        return "";
    }        

    /// <summary>
    ///     Allows the programmer to easily insert into the DB
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tableName">The table into which we insert the data.</param>
    /// <param name="data">A dictionary containing the column names and data for the insert.</param>
    /// <returns>A boolean true or false to signify success or failure.</returns>
    public bool Insert(String tableName, Dictionary<String, String> data)
    {
        String columns = "";
        String values = "";
        Boolean returnCode = true;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> val in data)
        {
            columns += String.Format(" {0},", val.Key.ToString());
            values += String.Format(" '{0}',", val.Value);
        }
        columns = columns.Substring(0, columns.Length - 1);
        values = values.Substring(0, values.Length - 1);
        try
        {
            this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("insert into {0}({1}) values({2});", tableName, columns, values));
        }
        catch (Exception fail)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(fail.Message);
            returnCode = false;
        }
        return returnCode;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection string might be fine, but it's never being set.  Because you never call the `SQLiteDatabase()` function to set it.

It looks like you intended for that to be a *constructor*, not an invokable method.  Something like this:

```
public SQLiteDatabase()
{
    dbConnection = "Data Source = StockDB.s3db; Version = 3;";
}
```

(Note the lack of the `void` keyword.)

Or perhaps this:

```
public DBHelper()
{
    dbConnection = "Data Source = StockDB.s3db; Version = 3;";
}
```

Depends on what the *class* is actually named.

---

Note: It's also worth pointing out that your code is currently open to SQL injection attacks.  You should take a look at parameterized queries instead of directly concatenating values like that.  Currently you're potentially allowing users to execute arbitrary code on your database, which is a very bad thing.  Query parameters treat such input as *values* instead of as *executable code*.

Comment: Probably the class is the one named DBHelper in the last example

Comment: Without the comma between the values it is safe for the moment. :-)

Comment: @Steve: You're probably right (first comment), though that method header comment needs to change (or be removed) too :)  (second comment) Unless the first value is the one being compromised and the rest is commented.  Which was the first thing I thought of, bobby tables and all :)

Comment: If i use your first solution then it says the method must have a return type... The class is dbhelper and the method is SQLiteDatabase()

Comment: @Cleaven: That means it's not a constructor.  The constructor has to be the same name as the class it constructs.

Comment: @David I've now added the full DBHelper class for you to see, if you need it, I've been trying everything and nothing works.

Comment: @Cleaven: It looks like the one thing you *didn't* try is what's described in this answer.  If you want the connection string set in a constructor, put it in a constructor.

Comment: @David I will look this up and try it and get back to you, still learning about code so I'm just going to play around with it a little bit.

Comment: @David Sorry, I misunderstood you the entire time, I was confused but i read it over again and got it now, i will mark your answer as correct and post my class as another answer, Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 dbConnection = "Data Source = StockDB.db3;";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the class looks like in order to work.

```
namespace Stock_A_Lot
{
public class DBHelper
{

    String dbConnection;
    /// <summary>
    ///     Default Constructor for DBHelper Class.
    /// </summary>
    public DBHelper()
    {
        dbConnection = "Data Source = StockDB.s3db; Version = 3;";
    }

    /// 
   /* /// <summary>
    ///     Single Param Constructor for specifying the DB file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputFile">The File containing the DB</param>
    public void SQLiteDatabase(String inputFile)
    {
        dbConnection = String.Format("Data Source={0}", inputFile);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Single Param Constructor for specifying advanced connection options.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionOpts">A dictionary containing all desired options and their values</param>
    public void SQLiteDatabase(Dictionary<String, String> connectionOpts)
    {
        String str = "";
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> row in connectionOpts)
        {
            str += String.Format("{0}={1}; ", row.Key, row.Value);
        }
        str = str.Trim().Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
        dbConnection = str;
    }*/

    /// <summary>
    ///     Allows the programmer to run a query against the Database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sql">The SQL to run</param>
    /// <returns>A DataTable containing the result set.</returns>
    public DataTable GetDataTable(string sql)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
            cnn.Open();
            SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
            mycommand.CommandText = sql;
            SQLiteDataReader reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(reader);
            reader.Close();
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
        return dt;
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///     Allows the programmer to interact with the database for purposes other than a query.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sql">The SQL to be run.</param>
    /// <returns>An Integer containing the number of rows updated.</returns>
    public int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)
    {
        SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
        cnn.Open();
        SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
        mycommand.CommandText = sql;
        int rowsUpdated = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn.Close();
        return rowsUpdated;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Allows the programmer to retrieve single items from the DB.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sql">The query to run.</param>
    /// <returns>A string.</returns>
    public string ExecuteScalar(string sql)
    {
        SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
        cnn.Open();
        SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
        mycommand.CommandText = sql;
        object value = mycommand.ExecuteScalar();
        cnn.Close();
        if (value != null)
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
        return "";
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Allows the programmer to easily update rows in the DB.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tableName">The table to update.</param>
    /// <param name="data">A dictionary containing Column names and their new values.</param>
    /// <param name="where">The where clause for the update statement.</param>
    /// <returns>A boolean true or false to signify success or failure.</returns>
    public bool Update(String tableName, Dictionary<String, String> data, String where)
    {
        String vals = "";
        Boolean returnCode = true;
        if (data.Count >= 1)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> val in data)
            {
                vals += String.Format(" {0} = '{1}',", val.Key.ToString(), val.Value.ToString());
            }
            vals = vals.Substring(0, vals.Length - 1);
        }
        try
        {
            this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("update {0} set {1} where {2};", tableName, vals, where));
        }
        catch
        {
            returnCode = false;
        }
        return returnCode;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Allows the programmer to easily delete rows from the DB.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tableName">The table from which to delete.</param>
    /// <param name="where">The where clause for the delete.</param>
    /// <returns>A boolean true or false to signify success or failure.</returns>
    public bool Delete(String tableName, String where)
    {
        Boolean returnCode = true;
        try
        {
            this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("delete from {0} where {1};", tableName, where));
        }
        catch (Exception fail)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(fail.Message);
            returnCode = false;
        }
        return returnCode;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Allows the programmer to easily insert into the DB
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tableName">The table into which we insert the data.</param>
    /// <param name="data">A dictionary containing the column names and data for the insert.</param>
    /// <returns>A boolean true or false to signify success or failure.</returns>
    public bool Insert(String tableName, Dictionary<String, String> data)
    {
        String columns = "";
        String values = "";
        Boolean returnCode = true;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> val in data)
        {
            columns += String.Format(" {0},", val.Key.ToString());
            values += String.Format(" '{0}',", val.Value);
        }
        columns = columns.Substring(0, columns.Length - 1);
        values = values.Substring(0, values.Length - 1);
        try
        {
            this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("insert into {0}({1}) values({2});", tableName, columns, values));
        }
        catch (Exception fail)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(fail.Message);
            returnCode = false;
        }
        return returnCode;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Allows the programmer to easily delete all data from the DB.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A boolean true or false to signify success or failure.</returns>
    public bool ClearDB()
    {
        DataTable tables;
        try
        {
            tables = this.GetDataTable("select NAME from SQLITE_MASTER where type='table' order by NAME;");
            foreach (DataRow table in tables.Rows)
            {
                this.ClearTable(table["NAME"].ToString());
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Allows the user to easily clear all data from a specific table.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="table">The name of the table to clear.</param>
    /// <returns>A boolean true or false to signify success or failure.</returns>
    public bool ClearTable(String table)
    {
        try
        {

            this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("delete from {0};", table));
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
}
```